# OCaml Makefile: No Rule to Make Target

Tags: makefile, ocaml, gnu-make, ocamlbuild

I'm following this [OCamlbuild example](https://github.com/ocaml/ocamlbuild/tree/master/examples/03-packages), and accordingly have created the Makefile below:

```
OCB_FLAGS = -use-ocamlfind -I src -I lib
OCB = ocamlbuild $(OCB_FLAGS)

check: ocamlfind query core async
clean: $(OCB) -clean
byte: $(OCB) main.byte
native: $(OCB) main.native

.PHONY: check clean byte native
```

The root directory contains two sub-directories, *src* and *lib*. The *src* sub-directory contains the file *main.ml*.

When I execute any of the targets, e.g. `make clean`, `make byte`, etc., I receive the error message:

> make: *** No rule to make target 'ocamlfind', needed by 'check'. 
>   Stop.

or

> make: *** No rule to make target 'ocamlbuild', needed by 'byte'. 
>   Stop.

I'd appreciate help in understanding the cause of and solution to this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
clean: $(OCB) -clean
```

Means that `clean` has two dependencies, `$(OCB)` and `-clean`. So it tries to build `ocamlbuild` first.

You want this, as in the linked makefile:

```
clean:
        $(OCB) -clean
```

This means that `clean` has no dependencies, and is "done" by running `$(OCB) -clean`.

Note that you need an actual tab character before the `$` character, not 8 spaces.